# Forcing zero entries with unitary matrix operations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Starting with an arbitrary matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$,

$$ A = \left[\begin{array}[cc] 
        ** & * & * \\ * & * & * \\ * & * & *
       \end{array} \right] $$

where $*$ represents a any number. Produce

$$ A = \left[\begin{array}[cc] 
        ** & * & 0\\ 0& * & * \\ 0& 0& *
       \end{array} \right] $$

multiplying $A$ by unitary matrices only.

---

The first 2 columns can be done with Householder reflectors, but I don't see how to get the zero in the (1,3) entry.

Comment: You mean multiplying by unitary only from the left?

Comment: Looks kinda like Jordan normal form. You mean conjugating by unitary matrices? Or multiplying on left and right?

Comment: Multiplying on the left. If not possible a right multiplication is allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Product of unitary matrices is a unitary matrix, so we are to find, if possible, a unitary $U$ such that
$$
U^*A=\begin{bmatrix}* & *&0\\\color{red}0&*&*\\\color{blue}0&\color{blue}0&*\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Denote the columns of $U$ and $A$ as
$$
U=[U_1\ U_2\ U_3],\quad A=[A_1\ A_2\ A_3].
$$
We have that $\color{blue}{U_3\bot A_1}$ and $\color{blue}{U_3\bot A_2}$. If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are not parallel then the only possibility for $U_3$ is along $A_1\times A_2$. Now $\color{red}{U_2\bot A_1}$ and $U_2\bot U_3$ gives one possible line again for $U_2$. It leaves only one direction for $U_1$, and the value of $U_1^*A_3$ cannot be chosen arbitrary. In general, it is not possible to get the third zero for a generic $3\times 3$ matrix $A$.